# cannot boot from CD, MBR Error with no HDD attached

Tags: boot, mbr

I'm trying to get an older 32 bit computer up and running.

I set BIOS to boot from CD 1st, HDD 2nd. It gets to "Boot from CD" but it never gets to "Press any key to boot from CD".

The screen just goes blank or sometimes MBR Error appears.

The HDD works fine in another computer. I even get this when I disconnect the HDD. I have 4 spare CD drives, tried them all with same error. I cleaned them, I reburned the boot disk. Same error, can't boot a thing with the CD. The boot disk works fine in other computers.

The CD drive is set as the Master disk on the Secondary Controller.

Seems like it must be a motherboard error, perhaps IDE controller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Set the optical drive as cable select and put it on the primary ide channel if you can.

If no joy try replacing the ide cable with a new one, (80 wire)

Comment: I'll give it a go in a couple of days (tired of working on it right now). Any other comments are welcome, I'll try them.